# PDE problem: how to show that it can have a unique solution

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with this exercise:

Consider the following system of coupled first-order nonlinear partial differential equations for the scalar-valued function $u=u(x,y)$:

$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=f(x,y,u)$

$c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+d\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=g(x,y,u) $

$(*)$

Here $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are given smooth functions of $x$ and $y$ and we assume that  $ab-dc$ $\neq$ $0$ for all $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Show that the system has a unique solution for all initial data $u(x_0,y_0)=u_0$ if and only if
$[\mathbb{V},\mathbb{W}]=r\mathbb{V}+s\mathbb{W}$, $(**)$
where $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ are the vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$\mathbb{V}(x,y,z)=(a(x,y),b(x,y),f(x,y,z))$ and $\mathbb{W}(x,y,z)=(c(x,y),d(x,y),g(x,y,z))$
for some functions $r(x,y,z)$ and $s(x,y,z)$

Now my problem is that I don't know where to start, I tried to use the Froebinus theorem but without suceed. I don't manipulate well PDE and it doesn't help me. Please can you explain me how to really understand this exercise ?

Regards,
Herosix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to be true. The scheme of the proof is the following.

Let us suppose that $a \equiv 1, b \equiv 0, c \equiv 0, d \equiv 1$. We can always achieve it by solve the equation explicitly (I believe that you made a type and the determinant of the system is not null). Thus, let us consider the system

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f(x,y,u)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=g(x,y,u) $

The formal condition of solvability of the equation above is
$\frac{d f}{d y} = \frac{d g}{d x}$, or

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + g\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$

$(1)$

On the other hand, if we compute Lie bracket of the fields $\mathbb{V} = (1, 0, f)$ and $\mathbb{W} = (0, 1, g)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields for example) we will come to

$[\mathbb{V},\mathbb{W}]=(0, 0, \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+f\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}-g\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$

It is easy to see that it is equal to $r\mathbb{V}+s\mathbb{W}$ IFF $r\equiv0,s\equiv0$ and (1) is satisfied (please see also http://www.math.tamu.edu/~jml/EDSpublic.pdf  Example 1.2.3)

P.S. I believe it is possible to do similar direct calculation for arbitrary $a, b, c, d$ functions. It might be pretty cumbersome but finally will lead you to correct result. I also believe that there exists more nice "modern" way to prove it :)